# Using c++ Winsock works with two applications on one computer but not on separate computers.

Tags: c++, client, winsock

I'll post my code but I don't necessarily need it looked at. I just want to know if the error is most likely with the code, or if my issue is expected. This is my first time trying this. I've really just copied the Winsock server/client example posted on MSDN. I've disabled firewalls and that didn't help. Do I need to look into something like Port Forwarding or are there settings for the functions (getaddrinfo, connect, listen, ect..) that affect this, or should it theoretically connect when the server and client are run on two separate computers if two applications connect when run on the same computer?

Here is my server:

```
int server(){
WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult;
int i;

SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
struct addrinfo hints;
char sendbuf[sizeof(me)];

char ip[40];
int iSendResult;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
int timer = GetTickCount();

printf("Opening server socket\n");

// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}

ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

// Resolve the server address and port
iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
if ( iResult != 0 ) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Setup the TCP listening socket
iResult = bind( ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

freeaddrinfo(result);

iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

//This part just displays computer hostname and IP address to input in the client
if(gethostname(ip, sizeof(ip))!=0){

    std::cout << "ERROR: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
}
i=0;
std::cout << "Host name is ";

   struct hostent *phe = gethostbyname(ip);
if (phe == 0) {
    std::cerr << "Yow! Bad host lookup." << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

i=0;
while(ip[i]!=NULL)
    std::cout << ip[i++];



for (i = 0; phe->h_addr_list[i] != 0; ++i) {
    struct in_addr addr;
    memcpy(&addr, phe->h_addr_list[i], sizeof(struct in_addr));
    std::cout << "Address " << i << ": " << inet_ntoa(addr) << std::endl;
}


// Accept a client socket
ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}


// No longer need server socket
closesocket(ListenSocket);


// Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
do{
    while(GetTickCount()-timer<(1000/(2.0*FPS)))
        Sleep(SLEEPTIMER);

    me[0]=cx;
    me[1]=cy;
    me[2]=dr;
    me[3]=at;

    memcpy(sendbuf, me, sizeof(float)*4);
    iResult = send( ClientSocket, sendbuf, sizeof(float)*4, 0 );
    iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    memcpy(them, recvbuf, sizeof(float)*4);

    std::cout << sizeof(me) << std::endl;

    if (iResult == 0)
        printf("Connection closing...\n");

} while (iResult > 0);

// shutdown the connection since we're done
iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// cleanup
closesocket(ClientSocket);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
}
```

here is my client:

```
int __cdecl client() 
{
printf("Opening clent socket\n");
WSADATA wsaData;
SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                *ptr = NULL,
                hints;
char sendbuf[sizeof(me)];
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int iResult;
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
char *init = "this is a test";
int timer = GetTickCount();

std::string  ip;
PCSTR ip_c;


//window.setFramerateLimit(1);

std::cout << "Enter the IP address of the server: ";
std::cin >> ip;

//memcpy(&ip_c, &ip, sizeof(ip));

/* // Validate the parameters
if (argc != 2) {
    printf("usage: %s server-name\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
}*/

// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}

ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

// Resolve the server address and port
iResult = getaddrinfo(ip.c_str(), DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
if ( iResult != 0 ) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) {
    printf("Attempting to connect\n");
    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, 
        ptr->ai_protocol);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    cnct=1;
    printf("Connecting\n");
    std::cout << ptr->ai_addr << std::endl;
    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        continue;
    }
    break;
}

freeaddrinfo(result);

if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

printf("Sending\n");


// Send an initial buffer
iResult = send( ConnectSocket, init, (int)strlen(init), 0 );
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);


while(1){
    while(GetTickCount()-timer<(1000/(2.0*FPS)))
        Sleep(20);

    timer = GetTickCount();

    me[0]=cx;
    me[1]=cy;
    me[2]=dr;
    me[3]=at;

    memcpy(sendbuf, me, sizeof(float)*4);
    iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, sizeof(float)*4, 0 );
    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    memcpy(them, recvbuf, sizeof(float)*4);

    std::cout << me[1] << std::endl;


}

// shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Receive until the peer closes the connection
do {

    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if ( iResult > 0 )
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
    else if ( iResult == 0 )
        printf("Connection closed\n");
    else
        printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

} while( iResult > 0 );

// cleanup
closesocket(ConnectSocket);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: when run on two computers the server runs fine and the client gives the "Unable to connect to server!\n" line

Also two computers are connected to same router

Comment: And their firewall situation? (I had to ask).

Comment: I'm no expert and wrote my first client/server app just few weeks ago. Anyway, if you try to connect to a server that's behind a router, only the router IP address is visible to the internet, thus yes you should setup port forwarding to the IP address of the server PC in LAN to connect properly to that server.

Comment: I disabled the firewall on both sides. Thanks JarkkoL, that's the kind of answer I"m looking for. I'll try that.

Comment: The documentation doesn't seem to say what IP address is returned by `getaddrinfo` if you don't pass a node name, so perhaps you're binding the wrong address; IIRC, you should bind 0.0.0.0 to listen on all available addresses.  You can use `netstat` to check which address you're binding to.